# jquery- changing css but can't reset to original-fadein() causes program to stop working too

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I am trying to change the background color to blue and also make it fade in fade out. I also want the background color to get back to normal when a button is clicked (it's a game, and when you click the play again button the game is being reset, and you start from the beginning).

How do I change the background color back to the original--would I do that within the function that is being invoked when I click on the playagain button? How would I set it back to normal?

Also, the fadein() fadeout() causes the game to stop working.  So after fadein, fadeout nothing works anymore..

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

```
$('#results').append("<p>You won! 
</p>").appendTo('#results').css({fontSize:'40px'}).fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut 
();
 $('body').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
```

Comment: Why did you do this? `$('#results').append("...").appendTo('#results')`

Comment: I don't know haha but yea thats wrong, however it doesn't affect the result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the behavior you want, and we can't tell what's making your code stop, from what you posted, but here is what I tried:

```js
$('#playBtn').click(function() {
    var number_of_fadings = 4;

    $('#playBtn').hide();
    $('#results').append("<p>You won!</p>");

    (function doFadeInOut() {
        $('#results').fadeIn().fadeOut(function() {
            number_of_fadings--;
            if (number_of_fadings > 0) { doFadeInOut(); }
            else { $('#restartBtn').show(); }
        });
    })();

    $('body').css({ 'background': '#09f' });
});

$('#restartBtn').click(function() {
    $('body').css({ 'background': '#fff' });
    $('#playBtn').show();
    $('#restartBtn').hide();
    $('#results').empty();
});
```

```css
body{ font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#restartBtn, #results { display: none; }
#results p{ padding: 1em; font-size: 2em; text-align: center; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="playBtn">Play</button>
<button id="restartBtn">Restart the game</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```